# Bash backup script from config file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract database names from a config file and iterate over each db name to backup it
The config file looks like this:

```
#
# Databases:
#
BASE_1 = /firebird/data/BASE_1.fdb
BASE_2 = /firebird/data/BASE_2.fdb
BASE_3 = /firebird/data/BASE_3.fdb
# .../...
```

And my script looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

db_conf='./scripts/databases.conf'
bk_dir='./backups'

dbs=$(grep -E -o "[A-Z_]+\.fdb" $db_conf | sort | uniq)

for db in $dbs
do
  gbak -b "localhost:${db/.fdb/}" "$bk_dir/${db/.fdb/.fbk}" -user xxx -pass xxx
done
```

The script is working but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found this way, that is the best as I know:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

db_conf='/firebird/etc/databases.conf'
bk_dir='/firebird/backups'
data_dir='/firebird/data'

dbs=$(grep -Eo "$data_dir/[A-Z0-9_]+\.fdb" $db_conf | cut -d/ -f4 | cut -d. -f1 | sort | uniq)

for db in $dbs
do
  if test -f "$data_dir/${db}.fdb"; then
    echo "backup ${db} to $bk_dir/${db}.fbk"
    gbak -b "${db}" "$bk_dir/${db}.fbk"
  else
    echo "${db}.fdb not found"
  fi
done
```